# Tensorflow Fairness Indicators for Multiclass output

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-analysis

According to the [github page for tensorflow fairness-indicators](https://github.com/tensorflow/fairness-indicators) :

> Fairness Indicators enables easy computation of commonly-identified fairness metrics for **binary and multiclass classifiers**.

However, I'm unable to find any example using tf-fairness-indicators for multiclass classifier/output. The examples mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/responsible_ai/fairness_indicators/tutorials/Fairness_Indicators_Pandas_Case_Study) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/responsible_ai/fairness_indicators/tutorials/Fairness_Indicators_Example_Colab) demonstrates the usage only for `binary-class`, without giving any idea how to extend this for `multiclass-classifiers`.

Do we have any reference/documented approach for extending this to multiclass-classifiers ?